# Predicting a real number in a fixed range

Tags: regression

Suppose we need to predict a real number in fixed range, for example, [0 .. 5], and our Y can be 3.14, 2.4654 etc.
What is the name of this kind of tasks (to be able to search further) and what are the approaches to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a regression problem with a ["limited dependent variable"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited_dependent_variable).

One very common approach is to use a [sigmoid transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) as the final step in your model.  For example, the logistic transform $f(x) = \frac{5}{1 + e^{-x}}$ is constrained to the interval [0, 5].